# Keep url in address bar with a proxy reverse on nginx

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, reverse-proxy, cname-record, proxypass

I have a web application where users can create their page. The web application will generate a URL like this for each page created : https://my-domain.com/page/12345. I would like to give my users the possibility to use their own domain / subdomain instead of this URL on my website by just pointing a cname record to my server.

So I ran some tests with another domain I have on Cloudflare and created the following cname record :

```
subdomain.domain.com.   1   IN  CNAME   my-web-app-domain.com.
```

Basically, I want `subdomain.domain.com` to point to my web app domain so my users can access their page using `subdomain.domain.com`.

To achieve that on my target web app server that uses nginx, I have created the following block in my nginx config file :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my-web-app-domain.com/page/12345;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

So this basically works but instead of keeping `subdomain.domain.com` in the address bar, it redirects the user to `http://my-web-app-domain.com/page/12345`. How can I modify my code so it keeps `subdomain.domain.com` instead of redirecting?

In case it's useful, my web app uses Laravel and to test if it may be the issue, I have added this into my TrustProxies.php file but it's still the same :

```
protected $proxies = '*';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that your Laravel application expects HTTP Host header to be `my-web-app-domain.com`, but it is something else. This mismatch makes the application to redirect to the correct application domain.

Try adding `proxy_set_header Host my-web-app-domain.com;` to your configuration.